# How to do integration testing in Clojure?

Tags: testing, clojure, integration-testing, ring, core.async

What are the techniques and libraries to do the integration testing in Clojure. Specifically interaction with databases, ring applications, core.async channels, anything which produces a side-effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ring-mock](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-mock) for ring applications. An example of creating a mock handler and using it is:

```
(let [h (-> (POST "/some/url" [] some-resource)
            (wrap-defaults api-defaults))]
  (let [resp (h (-> (request :post "/some/url")
                    (header "content-type" "application/json")
                    (body (generate-string {:foo :bar}))))]
    (is (= 303 (:status resp)))
    (is (= "" (:body resp)))
    (is (= "http://some/place/foo" (get-in resp [:headers "Location"])))))
```

For d/b interation testing and side-effects, I use [with-redefs](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/with-redefs/) to stub out the actual side-effecting function and capture and test the arguments to it are as expected. I'm not sure if this is idiomatic, but it's what I've found the easiest, e.g.

```
(testing "some d/b work"
  (let [insert-data (ref {})]
    (with-redefs
      [d/insert-data<! 
       (fn [db data] (dosync (alter insert-data assoc :db db)
                             (alter insert-data assoc :data data)))]
      (let [d (your-fn your-args)]
        (is (= {:some :expected-result} d))
        (is (= {:db {:some :connection-data} :data {:some :expected-data}} @insert-data))))))
```

You can use atoms here, historically I've had to use refs when I was testing some agents that did write-back work, and atoms didn't work in that scenario.

The main library I use is [clojure.test](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html), I only briefly dabbled with property testing using [test.check](https://github.com/clojure/test.check) so far. I used [Midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje) for a while, but found clojure.test felt purer, but that was down to taste. Plus if you're venturing into cljs, you may as well stick with one testing framework.

I haven't any experience using core.async, but [its own tests](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/test/cljs/cljs/core/async/tests.cljs) look like a good place to start.

Comment: This answer is more helpful for unit testing. The setup of integration testing highly depends on circumstances.